# Error HH604: Error running JSON-RPC server: Connect Timeout Error

Tags: hardhat, json-rpc, hardhat-deploy, forks

I'm facing an error while running the command "yarn hardhat node"
ERROR:

```
Error HH604: Error running JSON-RPC server: Connect Timeout Error

For more info go to https://hardhat.org/HH604 or run Hardhat with --show-stack-traces
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

I've already tried "--openssl-legacy-provider" tag but its not working.

Package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "flashloans_hardhat",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-chai-matchers": "^1.0.0",
    "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-network-helpers": "^1.0.0",
    "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox": "^2.0.1",
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers": "^2.0.0",
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan": "^3.0.0",
    "@openzeppelin/contracts": "^2.5.0",
    "@studydefi/money-legos": "^2.4.2",
    "@typechain/ethers-v5": "^10.1.0",
    "@typechain/hardhat": "^6.1.2",
    "@types/chai": "^4.2.0",
    "@types/mocha": ">=9.1.0",
    "@uniswap/v2-periphery": "^1.1.0-beta.0",
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "hardhat": "^2.17.0",
    "hardhat-gas-reporter": "^1.0.8",
    "solidity-coverage": "^0.8.1",
    "ts-node": ">=8.0.0",
    "typechain": "^8.1.0",
    "typescript": ">=4.5.0"
  }
}
```

in **package.json** i only wanted to use `"@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox": "^2.0.1", "@openzeppelin/contracts": "^2.5.0", "@studydefi/money-legos": "^2.4.2", "@uniswap/v2-periphery": "^1.1.0-beta.0", "dotenv": "^16.0.3", "hardhat": "^2.12.6"` but yarn forces to download other unnecessary packages.

hardhat.config.js

```js
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox");
require("dotenv").config();
const privateKeys = process.env.PRIVATE_KEYS || "";

/** @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig */
module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.5.7",
  networks: {
    hardhat: {
      forking: {
        url: `https://eth-mainnet.g.alchemy.com/v2/${process.env.ALCHEMY_API_KEY}`,
      },
      timeout: 60000,
    },
  },
};
```

Please help in this regard